# Overlapping images in cocoa touch applications

Tags: cocoa-touch

I programatically created a box. It can be moved around the screen. The problem is that there are buttons on the screen I made in Interface Builder. When the box moves over a button, it covers the button. How can I make it appear behind the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your box to the view, instead of using `[view addSubview:box]` use `[view insertSubview:box atIndex:0]`.